# Routing in osm?

Tags: openstreetmap

As a part of my Software Development course I have to build a campus mapping mobile application which would include all the basic functionalities provided in google maps including searching,routing etc. Now in release 2 I have to implement routing.
Note: This is a completely offline application.
I have generated tiles rendered them in my application, implemented search location and present location.
Can somebody tell me how to perform routing in the map as i am in my second year and I have completely no knowledge of OSM?
Note: Also the application is to be cross platform..:)

Comment: If you have completely no knowledge of OSM the best place to start is to begin reading and playing with the API. If you have no knowledge of the API at this point, any answer given will either be too general to be if use, or too specific to be immediately understood. Try playing around with it first, take some time to get to know how it works and go from there. The first and second google search result using your title as the search param gives you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/) contains a lot of information about [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing). You should read about [OSM's basic elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [OSM tags for routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing). If you get stuck at some point then take a look at one of the many [online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers), [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) and [libraries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Libraries.2FDevelopment-Tools), several of them are open source.